# How to configure ufw to work with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ufw

I set DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY to ACCEPT as recommended in [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/enable-ufw-forwarding) but seems it's not enough, etcd is not accessible from my containers.

Comment: what are you trying to do? you should not access etcd directly, but you should get metadat through the API.

Comment: ^ +1. Don't reuse the etcd which k8s uses internally. If you need one for your application, please setup a different instance like [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/storage/vitess).